# The field is too small to accept the amount of data you attempted to add when writing to excel

Tags: c++, excel, visual-c++, ado

I am getting this error, when i am writing Cstring data to xls file in VC++.
Actually I am reading data from Different column in same file. After doing some operations i am placing it back in a different column in the same file, For small data it has accepted.
Once the larger size message comes, it is throwing an exeception and breaks.

Code for function is pasted below :

```
void CLoadOcxDlg::read(std::string excelFile, int sheetIndex, bool header, std::string csvFile)
{
clock_t t1 = clock();

std::cout << "reading " << excelFile;

  if(FAILED(::CoInitialize(NULL))) return;

  _RecordsetPtr pSchema = NULL;
  _RecordsetPtr pRec = NULL;

  int cellCount = 0;

  try
  {
      _bstr_t connStr(makeConnStr(excelFile, header).c_str());

      TESTHR(pRec.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Recordset)));       
      TESTHR(pRec->Open(sqlSelectSheet(connStr, sheetIndex).c_str(), connStr, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText));
      //TESTHR(pRec->Open(sqlSelectSheet(connStr, sheetIndex).c_str(), connStr, adOpenKeyset, adLockUnspecified, adCmdText));   

      std::ofstream stream(csvFile.c_str());

      while(!pRec->adoEOF)
      {
          for(long i = 8; i < pRec->Fields->GetCount(); )//++i)
          {
              CString Label = pRec->Fields->GetItem("LABEL/SMI")->Value;  

              if((Label == "AA") || (Label == "A6") || (Label == "BA") || (Label == "B6"))
              {

                  CString str  = pRec->Fields->GetItem(i + 8)->Value;
                  //_variant_t v = pRec->Fields->GetItem(i+8)->Value;
                  //if((v.vt == VT_R8) || (v.vt == VT_BSTR)) 
                  CString baseString = "/";

              {

                  if(str.GetLength())
                  {
                      int iCount = 0;

                      iCount = str.ReverseFind('/');
                  //Removing the Message part before '/'
                      str.Delete(0,iCount+1);
                      //CString baseString = "/";
                      baseString.Append(Label);
                      baseString.Append(" ");
                      baseString.Append(str);
                      baseString.Delete(baseString.GetLength() - 5,baseString.GetLength()); 
                      //pRec->Fields->GetItem(i + 9)->Value = _variant_t(baseString);
                  }



                  m_strDecodedMesg = m_ctrlDecoder.DecodeMessage(baseString);

                  long length = m_strDecodedMesg.GetLength();

                  m_strDecodedMesg.Insert(0,'"');
                  m_strDecodedMesg.Insert((m_strDecodedMesg.GetLength()+1),'"');                                
                  stream <<m_strDecodedMesg

                  **pRec-="">
  Fields->GetItem("DECODED_MESSAGE")->Value = _variant_t(m_strDecodedMesg);**

  pRec->Fields->GetItem("LENGTH")->Value = _variant_t(length);

  DataTypeEnum ctype;
  ctype = pRec->Fields->GetItem("DECODED_MESSAGE")->GetType();

  TESTHR(pRec->Update());

  }
  ++cellCount;
  }
  else
  {

  stream << _T("\" \"");
          }
          stream << std::endl;
          pRec->MoveNext();
          /*if(pRec->adoEOF)
          MessageBox("Decoding is Completed");*/
        }

      }


  }
  catch(_com_error &e)
  {
  _bstr_t bstrDescription(e.Description());
  CharToOem(bstrDescription, bstrDescription);
  std::cout << bstrDescription << std::endl;
  }
  //if(connStr->State == adStateOpen) connStr->Close();   
  ::CoUninitialize();


  clock_t t2 = clock();
  double t = (double)(t2 - t1) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;    
  std::cout << ": " << t << " sec; " << cellCount / t << " cells/sec" << "; see " << csvFile << std::endl;   
}
```

Comment: It would help if you provided the exception that you get with any information it provides. Have you considered stepping through it with a debugger?

Comment: After steeping through it with a debugger, I found this exception "The field is too small to accept the amount of data you attempted to add. Try inserting or pasting less data".

Answer (score 1):

the problem will be solved if you prepare  several things such as :

1. Delete the row, which you change (using properly way,, meaning properly sql query, or possibly another similar approach ,, Excel cells  are on the top ,what we can see, at the background is a  Data Base,you know ... Table name is a  sheet name ...etc. ,, this ADO,Microsoft ...  )
2. After that using  the field  names you can re-arrange the row, which is interesting for you, keeping to the Type of The Fields :)

I just finish one similar task as Add On to Bio metrical access_control software, using the functions (which you can use )   :

```
    pCmd->Execute(NULL, NULL, adCmdText);
   TESTHR(pRec.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Recordset)));
    pRec->Open("SELECT * FROM MySheet", _variant_t((IDispatch*)pCon), adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText);

    TESTHR(pRec->Update());
    TESTHR(pRec->Close());                
}
catch(_com_error &e)
{        
    _bstr_t bstrDescription(e.Description());      
    CharToOem(bstrDescription, bstrDescription);
    std::cout << bstrDescription << std::endl;
}
```

The mater is pretty much specific and too much complex  for time to time tasks only. 
I remember what Kraig Bruckshmidt (author of bestseller  books for OLE and COM ) is told to David Kruglinski at  Component Object Model : "David, when I started with COM,the first  six months ware a fog for me."

It is not possible to explain all at once.
If you have a questions or need  an advice  I am open.